# What do you call a person who drinks alcohol with someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, nouns

Someone you are drinking beer with. Someone who goes out for drinks with you.

Not necessarily a close friend but is present during a drink with you.

Comment: Drink buddy...?

Comment: I use **beer buddy**.

Answer (score 3):

A ***[drinking buddy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drinking%20buddy)***:

> - some one who is almost always there when you drink.

From [A West Texas Soapbox](https://books.google.it/books?id=nNo7uzvIkgYC&pg=PA69&dq=%22drinking%20buddy%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxgIzK5pzNAhUKtBoKHWblAkcQ6AEIUTAF#v=onepage&q=%22drinking%20buddy%22&f=false):

> - My best drinking buddy, Mike Cronin, laughed and said that Sanderson had the aesthetic of a plumber.

The expression has been used  from the '50s ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drinking%20buddy%2Cdrink%20buddy&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrinking%20buddy%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: Is *beer buddy* not popular from where you are?

Comment: @vickyace - beer buddy is also used:http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beer%20buddy

Comment: I was thinking *drinking buddy* must be more popular than *beer buddy* which is why you used the former. Or maybe some other reason. Both are good.

Comment: @vickyace - it actually is, at least according to https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drinking+buddy%2Cbeer+buddy&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrinking%20buddy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeer%20buddy%3B%2Cc0 - OP is asking for "a person who drinks alchool" and drinking is more generic.

Comment: The link is good but people are more reliable, that is why I asked you. Also,  all this talk has made me thirsty. :)

Comment: You should also add *drinking partner*, it's fairly common, and it's more BrEng friendly. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drinking+partner%2Cdrinking+buddy&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrinking%20partner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrinking%20buddy%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: A thorough reading of any Charles Bukowski novel would probably render a fair share of suggestions.